# htaccess with conditional rewritebase

Tags: ssl, .htaccess, rewritecond

I have a site (`the-tack-shop.co.uk`) in which I'm testing my e-commerce framework on. I was trying to test payment using a shared SSL: https://web43.secure-secure.co.uk/the-tack-shop.co.uk/.

I had to change my `htaccess` file to work with the SSL:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} secure-secure\. [NC]
RewriteBase /the-tack-shop.co.uk/
RewriteRule ^[a-z0-9\-_/\.]*$ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} the-tack-shop\. [NC]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^[a-z0-9\-_/\.]*$ index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^.* http://www.google.com [L]
```

This will work with the SSL domain, but not with the normal domain. Comment out the second rewritebase and it will work on the normal domain but not on the SSL domain.

Can anybody please tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Apache is perfectly capable of doing what you are asking, however, the [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) directive is not the prescribed way of achieving your desired results.

You have two options:

1. Instead of using RewriteBase, just specify the base path in your `RewriteRule` declarations
2. Create separate [NameVirtualhost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/vhosts/name-based.html) declarations instead of relying upon a catch-all

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for some similar solution. This one might help:

http://www.unitedforums.co.uk/vb/website-development-scripting/12597-htaccess-mod_rewrite-rules-both-urls.html#post73343

Comment: Hello, welcome to Serverfault. It's preferable if your answer can contain the full text of a solution, rather than a link to another site, links stop work sometimes and we would like SF to be the repository of answers, not links to answers.